# Can you use Power-loss Recovery when printing from OctoPrint?

Tags: marlin, octoprint, power-loss-recovery

As per the Marlin documentation for G-code [M413 - Power-loss Recovery](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M413.html):

> When Power-loss Recovery is enabled, and Marlin runs a print job **from the SD Card or Flash Drive**, it periodically saves the print job state to the SD Card / Flash Drive. If the machine crashes or a power outage occurs, Marlin presents the option to resume the interrupted print job.

If the printer is controlled by a host over USB instead (such as OctoPrint), can you still use Power-loss Recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an OctoPrint plugin that attempts to achieve exactly that. The plugin is called [OctoPrint-PowerFailure](https://plugins.octoprint.org/plugins/powerfailure/) and it's page describes:

> OctoPrint-PowerFailure attempts to recover a print after a power failure or printer disconnect. It is intended as a last resort and does not replace the use of proper power backup and appropriate communication setups. Recovered parts are certain to show small defects, but this may be acceptable in some cases.